# Disadvantages of using Swift in Objective-C code?

Tags: objective-c, swift, bridging-header

Lately there was an Objective-C project where I was in charge for some updates.
My main language is Swift and my Objectiv-C knowledge is lacking a little bit.

In a moment of frustration I was asking myself: Why not creating a bridging header to do the "heavy lifting" (programming classes) in Swift and do only basic stuff in Objective-C?

Are there some namespace/performance/whatever-issues with this approach or is it reasonable to save programming time for an objective-c noob like me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, an answer to this question is likely to be heavily dependent on one's opinion, and people here normally try to avoid this type of questions.

But anyway, introducing Swift code into an Objective-C codebase and replacing Objective-C code with Swift is what Apple appears to favor in their migration guide, see here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/migrating_your_objective_c_code_to_swift

Comment: There are some good points like "one class at a time". That is exactly what I thought about when thinking about if it is good to have a little bit of Swift here and there. The only "disadvantage" I can see right now is the impossibility to make Obj-C subclasses of Swift classes, isn't it?